# Apply a theme to an activity in Android

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm confused while reading some materials to set theme we use android:theme some like that, then where we can use its property?

Which property can be set in AndroidManifest.xml file for changing theme?

Comment: perhaps you want this - https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Answer (score 1):

In your **AndroidManifest.xml** `android:theme="@style/yourTheme"` in each activity p.e.

```
<activity
   android:name="com.example.helpingblind.Words"
   android:label="@string/title_activity_words"
   android:theme="@style/yourTheme1>
</activity>
<activity
   android:name="com.example.helpingblind.Words"
   android:label="@string/title_activity_words"
   android:theme="@style/yourTheme2>
</activity>
```

This way you can implement a theme in each activity if you want